# Slide index missing in Powerpoint edit mode

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

Somebody managed to turn the slide/outline navigator off by clicking the X shown in the image below.   I cannot find where to add it back.

[image]

I can still use the Slide Sorter view, but it's convenient to have the index as shown in the screengrab.

How do I re-enable the slide/outline navigator?

Comment: You can drag the scrollbar to the far left which causes it to hide - I think?! I'm not at my PC to test but I've seen this before

Comment: Makes sense but how do I un-hide it?

Comment: There is a X in the top right of this bar.  I've updated the image in the question to identify this X.   What is the name of this bar and/or how do we show it after clicking the X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since I figured how to do this.

How to hide/show the PowerPoint slide/outline navigator shown to the left in this screenshot:

To hide, click the X by the arrow.
[image]

Slide/outline navigator hidden: 
[image]

To show the navigator again, go to `View` then **double click** the `Normal` button: 
[image]

Navigator shown again: 
[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can move your mouse to the far left of the PowerPoint window and the cursor will change to the "window resize" style and allow you to drag it back in to view... I've just tried  your method of closing (by clicking the "X" - which worked) and then I could use my mouse to slide the panel back in to view.

Comment: Yep that works too.  Neither is exactly intuitive.  I expected to find a clearly marked setting under the View ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the "x" only closes the side index. To re-open, use the mouse to grab the leftmost screen-edge (though it looks blank), left-click on it and drag right to re-open.